# PDE in Fourier space

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have a coupled PDE. How can I convert the equation from $(x,t)$ to $(p,t)$, the Fourier space in MATHEMATICA?

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial d}{\partial t} = -4\gamma(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} +x (\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial d}{\partial x}) - \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 d}{\partial x^2})
\end{equation}

$\gamma$ is a constant.How can I write the corresponding equation in Fourier space?

```
Derivative[0, 1][c][x, t] + 
  Derivative[0, 1][d][x, 
   t] == -4 \[Gamma] (Derivative[1, 0][a][x, t] + 
    x (Derivative[1, 0][c][x, t] + Derivative[1, 0][d][x, t]) - 
    Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][d][x, t])
```

Comment: Please post code, no one will like to retype all your pretty Latex by themselves to test out possible solutions. I would try a replacement rule such as `/. {a[x, t] -> a[p, t] E^(I p x)}` then some simplification. But there'll be several caveats, without knowing the exact form of the input I can't give an exact solution.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, I have edited the text. How can I write the corresponding equation in p space?

Comment: Your code contains numerous elementary syntax errors. Please check it first.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch the code is fine, this is exactly how Mathematica renders derivatives + what is sent to the clipboard when you select and copy.

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP No, In the moment I have written my comment it has not been the case. Now it is OK.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch if I select the expression with derivatives typeset in superscript, click copy as -> plain text, what was in the question before the edit is *exactly* what I get when I paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 17.10.2017:** I've completely redone this to eliminate any manual labor.

Converting to Fourier space is quite simple. We must realize that any function

$$ f(x,t) = \int f(p, t) e^{i p x} dp $$

That is

```
f[x, t] = InverseFourierTransform[f[p, t], p ,x]
```

So the replacement rule I use is

```
rule =
  {Derivative[i_, j_][f_][x, t] :>
    D[InverseFourierTransform[f[p, t], p, x], {x, i}, {t, j}],
    f_[x, t] :> InverseFourierTransform[f[p, t], p, x]}
```

Let's define

```
expr = Derivative[0, 1][c][x, t] + Derivative[0, 1][d][x, t] == 
  -4 \[Gamma] (Derivative[1, 0][a][x, t] +
    x (Derivative[1, 0][c][x, t] + Derivative[1, 0][d][x, t]) - 
    Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][d][x, t]) // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> Derivative[0, 1][c][x, t] + Derivative[0, 1][d][x, t] +
>  4*\[Gamma]*(
>    Derivative[1, 0][a][x, t] +
>    x*(Derivative[1, 0][c][x, t] + Derivative[1, 0][d][x, t]) - 
>    Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][d][x, t]
>  ) == 0
> ```

The rhs is zero anyhow, so we do

```
FourierTransform[First@expr /. rule, x, p] // FullSimplify == 0
```

> $$ -4 i \gamma  p a(p,t)+4 \gamma  \left(\left(p^2-1\right) d(p,t)-p
>    \left(c^{(1,0)}(p,t)+d^{(1,0)}(p,t)\right)\right)+c^{(0,1)}(p,t)+4 \gamma  \left(p^2-1\right)
>    c(p,t)+d^{(0,1)}(p,t)=0 $$

I hope that now nothing is missed.

**UPDATE 19.10.17**

My rule can be simplified to

```
rule2 = f : Alternatives[a, b, c, d] :> (InverseFourierTransform[f[p, #2], p, #] &)
```

Then

```
FourierTransform[(expr // Expand // First) /. rule2, x, p] == 0
```

also gives the desired result.

Comment: But this kills the p^2 term which stems from the second derivative wrt x(which infact is not multiplied by x in the expression). Kindly take a look.

Comment: @Jyothi no, I don't think so. Note the leading `p` at the beginning of the expression and another one inside the brackets. Mathematica seems to have peculiar ways of simplifying things.

Comment: I've realized I had some typos in the answer, though not in the code. Please check the result now

Comment: @Jyothi I've eliminated any manually derived replacement rules and hopefully everything should be fine now.

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP Many thanks. This is perfect now!

Answer (score 1):

I did not notice the factor `x`. Sorry, below I repair this with the third rule.
Try the following. First introduce three simple rules:

```
rule1 = D[y_[x, t], {x, n_Integer}] :> -I^n*p^n*y[p, t];
rule2 = y_[x, t] :> y[p, t];
rule3 = x*y_[p, t] :> I*D[y[p, t], p]
```

And then apply them to your expression:

```
 expr = Derivative[0, 1][c][x, t] + 
       Derivative[0, 1][d][x, 
        t] == -4 \[Gamma] (Derivative[1, 0][a][x, t] + 
         x (Derivative[1, 0][c][x, t] + Derivative[1, 0][d][x, t]) - 
         Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][d][x, t]);

expr1=expr /. rule1 /. rule2//Expand
expr1 /. rule3
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Beat ya` to it :-) +1

Comment: Thanks  a lot. But still there is an x in the Fourier transformed equation.

Comment: The x shouldn't be there in the transformed equation, right?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, Yes, how can one define the appropriate replacement rule in that case?

Comment: Yes, this is what was bothering me. It would be of great help if you could help me with this

Comment: @Jyothi please see update in my answer below.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: Looks quite legit. I think the right way is to use the built-in FourierTransform but it doesn't have enough internal transformation rules even for a simple problem like this one, though it does know a few things.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch, But, the Fourier transform of $x \frac{\partial f }{\partial x} = - \tilde{f}(p) + p \tilde{f}'(p)$. Isn't it? Then, the evaluated expression is not correct, right? Kindly take a look.

Comment: @Jyothi  Look, I have shown the way. All the rest, including checking errors up is up to you.

Comment: @Jyothi $x f(x) \rightarrow i F'(p)$, that I'm pretty sure of. You're probably right, but so is Alexei in his comment :-)

Comment: Alexei, the guy's right, it turns out. `rule3` is only right in specific cases (e.g. applying it to `x f[p, t] p` would be wrong since `p` needs to be considered as a part of the pattern `y_[p, t]` but isn't).

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I do not tell that he is not right. I tell that I have given an idea. And I am not going to solve the whole problem for him and check for all errors. He should do all the rest himself, OK?

Comment: Hey, no need to be offended :-) I just think that it's not too great to showcase a rule that is mathematically incorrect. For OP's case he's responsible for checking correctness, but we should take care not to spread misinformation for subsequent visitors.